# uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord caused by factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

I get `uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord` whenever I try to run `rails db:migrate` and the backtrace seems to be pointing to a spec of `factory_girl`. The exact line that causes the error is

```
factory :test_user, class: User do
```

Why is that happening? How is that `ApplicationRecord` isn't defined when that spec is parsed? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have a file `application_record.rb` within your `app/models/` folder? Does it define `class ApplicationRecord `?

Comment: @slowjack2k No. Why should I have such a file? This is supposed to be a class defined by Rails itself.

Comment: Since Rails 5 a model file `application_record.rb` with class `ApplicationRecord` is generated. Every new model should inherit from that class instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was missing that file. Please post that same thing as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rails 5 a model file `application_record.rb` with class `ApplicationRecord` is generated. Every new model should inherit from that class instead of `ActiveRecord::Base` to prevent mokey patching of `ActiveRecord::Base`. `ApplicationRecord` is the new entry point for extensions.